# Find exact value of $P(1/2)$ given sum of pair of roots

Tags: polynomials

$$P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ The sum of pair of roots is given by $1,2,5,6,9,10$

I solved it by letting the roots $=\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ and then find them individually.

But since we have six equations and 4 variables, there's always a chance that system might become inconsistent.

Is there some way to do it without finding $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ and just using $a,b,c,d$ ?

PS
$\alpha=-3/2$
$\beta=5/2$
$\delta=7/2$
$\gamma=13/2$
P$(1/2)=-72$

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, it is possible that the system is inconsistent.

To check if it is (or not), let us define

$$  f_1=\alpha+\beta - 1 $$
$$ f_2=\alpha+\gamma- 2$$
$$  f_3=\alpha+\delta - 5 $$
$$  f_4=\beta+\gamma-6 $$
$$  f_5=\beta+\delta - 9 $$
$$  f_6=\gamma+\delta -10$$

and define a norm 
$$F=\sum_{i=1}^6 f_i^2$$

Compute the partial derivatives (this now leads to a square system) 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \alpha}=6 \alpha +2 \beta +2 \gamma +2 \delta -16$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \beta}=2 \alpha +6 \beta +2 \gamma +2 \delta -32$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \gamma}=2 \alpha +2 \beta +6 \gamma +2 \delta -36$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \delta}=2 \alpha +2 \beta +2 \gamma +6 \delta -48$$

Set each of them equal to $0$ since we look for the minimum of the norm $F$. This gives
$$\alpha= -\frac{3}{2}\qquad \beta = \frac{5}{2}\qquad \gamma =
   \frac{7}{2}\qquad\delta = \frac{13}{2}$$ and for these values $F=0$ : so, the system is consistent.

Now
$$P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$$ Replace $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ by their values and make $x=\frac 12$ to get the result which is effectively $-72$.

**However**, please notice that the values given in your PS are wrong for  $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Yep youre right, I copied them wrong. However, the problem still exists. I think partial derivatives takes this a bit too ahead. (This is supposed to be undergrad) the way I checked validity was by first find sum of all roots  = 11 then then if a+b=6 thus c+d=5. I don't know if it ensures validity or not. But it does reduce the chances of invalidity