# Let $p(x) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c, d$ are integers. The sum of the pair of roots are given by $1,2,5,6,9, 10$. find $p(\frac{1}{2})$.

Tags: polynomials

[image]Let $p(x) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c, d$ are integers. The sum of the pair of roots are given by $1,2,5,6,9, 10$. find $p(\frac{1}{2})$.

I tried it by solving for roots and got $\alpha=-1.5, \beta=2.5, \gamma=3.5$ and $\delta=6.5$. But upon putting it in for $a,b,c$ and $d$,I got that $c$ and $d$ are not integers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856578/given-a-polynomial-px-with-integer-coefficients-find-p-left-frac12-ri) over and over.  And please edit to show your work.  We can't tell you where you went wrong if we don't see what you did.  As a side note, there is more than one set of roots that give those pair sums.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, take a [tour]. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How about this $p(1/2)=-\frac{45225}{16}$? :-)

Comment: How did you get that @Math-fun

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your response. I've added my word on this problem. As you've suggested that there exist more than one set of roots that give these sums then how should I approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks for your response. I don't have the solution for this problem. Can you please support your answer for our better understanding? Thank you

Comment: Essentially the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759868/find-exact-value-of-p1-2-given-sum-of-pair-of-roots?rq=1

Comment: @Macavity That means the problem is wrong?

Comment: @user1150809 I will add details :-) in the meantime, sorry, I had a mistake in my calculations the value asked for is indeed $-72$.

Comment: @A4k45h  I believe there's only one integer valued answer...the posted solutions find the right one, ...though the one from RTX  found a false solution.

Comment: @user1150809 The problem is fine.  There are two possible solutions, $p(\frac12)\in \{-72, -585/16\}$; according to which you consider is bigger among $\alpha+\delta, \beta+\gamma$.  Only one these gives an integer $p(x)$ though.

Comment: I still have to analyse the solution, I didn’t get it till now

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment from @lulu drived me on the right way.

Using your notations, $p(x)$ has 4 roots, let us call them $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$, verifying $\alpha\le\beta\le\gamma\le\delta$. As all pair sums are distinct, we can even say that all roots are distinct so we have:
$$\alpha\lt\beta\lt\gamma\lt\delta$$

It is evident that we have $\alpha+\beta = 1$ and $\gamma+\delta = 10$.
But we cannot know a priori the order of $\alpha + \delta$ and $\beta+\gamma$

Knowing the sum of the lowest roots and the highest roots, we also know their average. So we can write:

$$\alpha = 0.5-h\\ \beta=0.5 + h\\ \gamma=5 - k\\ \delta=5+k$$
where $h\gt0$ and $k\gt0$

Again, $h+k = 3.5$ is evident, but we now have 2 possibilities, depending on the order of $\alpha + \delta$ and $\beta+\gamma$:

- Hyp. 1: $\alpha + \delta\le\beta+\gamma$

  We get $h-k=0.5$, so $h=2$ and $k=1.5$ which gives your solution:
  $$\alpha=-1.5, \beta=2.5, \gamma = 3.5 \text{ and } \delta=6.5$$
- Hyp. 2: $\alpha + \delta\ge\beta+\gamma$

  We get $k-h=0.5$, so $h=1.5$ and $k=2$ which now gives :
  $$\alpha=-1, \beta=2, \gamma = 3 \text{ and } \delta=7$$

It is now evident that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ will all be integers...

Comment: Excellent! I tried this problem for like $2.5$ hours but still didn’t got any clue on how to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this is quite easily solved by creating a system of equations :
$$p(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$$

note that a, b, c and d are integers therefore $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ too are integers.
and since the sums are 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 we have the sums of the roots being equal to 11 ( why? ).

so notice $$11 - r_1 - r_2 = r_3 + r_4$$
and also $$11 - r_3 - r_4 = r_1 + r_2$$
this is correct for other pairs as well.
thus we arrive at the system below.
$$
\{r_1 + r_2, r_3 + r_4\} = \{5, 6\}
$$
$$
\{r_1 + r_4, r_3 + r_2\} = \{2, 9\}
$$
and
$$
\{r_1+r_3, r_2+r_4\} = \{1, 5\}
$$
now notice that :
$$
(r_1+r_2) - (r_1+r_3) + (r_3+r_2) = 2r_2
$$
so of the three terms above either all three must be even or two must be odd and one, even.
therefore, we have either :
$$
r_1+r_2 = 5
$$
and
$$r_2 + r_3 = 2$$

or
$$
r_1+r_2 = 6
$$
and
$$r_2 + r_3 = 9$$
with $r_1 + r_3 \in \{1, 5\}$

to simplify we have :
$$
r_1 - r_3 = \pm 3
$$
and $r_1 + r_3 \in \{1, 5\}$
thus $$(r_1, r_3, r_2, r_4) \in \{(2, -1, 3, 7), (4, 1, 1, 5), (-1, 2, 7, 3), (1, 4, 5, 1)\}$$

now to evaluate the polynomial :
$p(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4) \Rightarrow p(\frac{1}{2}) \in \{\frac{63}{16}, \frac{-585}{16}\}$
But ! the $\{4, 1, 1, 5\}$ is unacceptable because there are no pairs that sum to 1, thus the answer shall be $\frac{-585}{16}$

Comment: Good analysis, but I'm not sure how you got $(4,1,1,5)$ as a possible answer.  No two of those sum to $1$, nor $10$.

Comment: oops, it is nearly 2 in the morning here i forgot to check for that!

Comment: No worries.  The other solution works.